# How to convert 'struct' to a stream of data?

Tags: rust, blockchain, bitcoin, rocksdb

I want to save a struct as a value in RocksDB and to do that, I want to codificate the Struct as a sequence of characters.

I know that is possible to convert to 'u8' using 'any_as_u8_slice'  (meshopt crate), but I don't find nothing to revert the conversion.

How could I convert the Struct in a sequence of characters that I could revert after?

Here are a peace of code:

```
fn main() {
let path = Path::new("/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin");
let dbB = BitcoinDB::new(path, true).unwrap();
let path = "/home/ubuntu/.rocksdb";
let db = DB::open_default(path).unwrap();
let m = 0;
let n = 2000;

for block in dbB.iter_block::<SBlock>(m, n) {
    for tx in block.txdata {
        //db.put(key, tx).unwrap();
    }
}
```

}

The idea is codificate 'tx', to add as part of the value in RocksDB.

I want to do this for improve the performance of getting a tx in the blockchain, adding indexes to the database. But just for range of blocks between 'm' and 'n'.

For iterate the blocks in the blockchain I am  using the following crate: https://crates.io/crates/bitcoin-explorer, so the 'tx' struct is already created.

Comment: Sounds like you want to serialize the struct (maybe with something like [zerocopy](https://docs.rs/zerocopy/latest/zerocopy/)). It would be helpful to have an example of the struct you're working with.

Comment: I dind't create the struct. This type is returned by an other tool. So I can't edit it. You cand find the struct here: https://docs.rs/bitcoin-explorer/latest/bitcoin_explorer/parser/proto/simple_proto/struct.STransaction.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Storing the byte-representation of an object is not portable and will break horribly when you inevitably change the structure. Look into serde for real serialization of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If and only if the original structs derived `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits**, then you could use [bincode](https://crates.io/crates/bincode) to serialize them into binary-encoded `Vec<u8>`.

Here I have a tuple struct `MyStruct` wrapped the original struct `StructFromAnotherTool` and use [hex](https://docs.rs/hex/latest/hex/fn.encode.html) to encode and decode the result from `Vec<u8>` to and from hex string so I could easily store the hex string representation in a database. Note that the structs derive `PartialEq` and `Debug` for an assertion in the end:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use hex;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct StructFromOtherTool {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct MyStruct(StructFromOtherTool);

fn main() { 
    let mystruct = MyStruct(SomeStruct { x: 1.3, y: 5.2 });

    let encoded: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(&mystruct).unwrap();

    // This hex string representation can be stored in a database.        
    let s = hex::encode(encoded.clone());

    println!("Hex encoded struct: {}", s);

    // We then decode the hex string and use bincode to deserialize back to a MyStruct entity.
    let v = hex::decode(s).unwrap();

    let decoded = bincode::deserialize(&v[..]).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(mystruct, decoded);
}
```